# Converting a vector of symbols to input for `...`

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, rlang, tidyeval

I have an R function where I want to turn a vector of symbols (`c(a, b)`) into input for `...` (e.g. `a, b`).

```
# create data
set.seed(1)
data <- dplyr::tibble(a = sample(1:5, size = 10, replace = TRUE),
                      b = sample(1:5, size = 10, replace = TRUE))
```

The function should look like the following:

```
f <- function(category) {
  # trying to work out
}
f(category = c(a,b))
```

and give the result:

```
data |>
  tidyr::expand(tidyr::nesting(a, b))
```

The difficulty is that my function supplies the inputs as a vector of symbols whereas `rlang::nesting` takes input as `...`.

How can I convert from one format to the other? Or should I use another function than `rlang::nesting`?

Comment: Why can't you define `f <- function(...) {category <- do.call(c, list(...))}`?

Comment: Are you able to expand on this idea @Roland? I'm not clear on how we can integrate this into an answer.

Comment: I probably could but you would need to ask a question that does not involve the tidyverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces where you supply a set of variables through `c()` should be based on tidyselect. The easiest way is to use `select()`.

First take a selection then splice in the data:

```
f <- function(data, category) {
  sel <- dplyr::select(data, {{ category }})
  tidyr::expand(data, tidyr::nesting(!!!sel))
}

f(data, category = c(a, b))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 2
#>       a     b
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     5
#> 3     2     2
#> 4     2     5
#> 5     3     1
#> 6     3     5
#> 7     4     5
```

Because you're interfacing through `select()` you gain all tidyselect features:

```
f(data, category = starts_with(c("a", "b")))
```